# File browser alternatives with remote connections

Tags: finder, remote-control, file

I have been linux person for 6 years, now converting to mac world.

I am looking for the file browser, which would enable me to:

- delete files and folders by pressing delete
- rename files by shortcut or right mouse button
- enter folders by pressing "Enter"
- navigating in the tree by shortcuts (keyboard only)

and also importantly:

- do the same things on REMOTE linux servers, especially edit files on the fly
- open remote text files in my favorite editor (whichever I want, such as Sublime)

In Ubuntu, I just typed to the directory address ssh://name@server and file system acted completely the same way as if I was on the local computer. Perfectly easy to use and understand.

I don't mind paying small/medium amount of money if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sshfs](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS) or [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) to mount SSH locations as local volumes.

↩ renames files in Finder. ⌘↓ or ⌘O opens files, ⌘⌫ moves files to the trash, and ⌥⌘V moves files copied with ⌘C.

You could also take a look at [Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com) or [Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com). Both support making return open files but not making forward delete move files to to the trash.

Comment: a little off topic, but... how is it you don't have a username?